# Problem in inserting data into database using Flask and MySQL

Tags: python, html, database, flask, mysql-python

I had used the flask and MySQL in my project, after inserting the users data into database it shows only the empty rows but the rows are counted but the rows are showed as empty row. I did tried many ways to solve this but i didn't solve. There is no solution over the internet.is there any one to help me to build my project. please help me!

This is my code

```
# from flask import Flask
# from flask import render_template

# app = Flask(__name__)


# @app.route("/")
# def index():
#     return render_template("index.html")
# @app.route("/login")
# def login():
#     return render_template("login.html")

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, session
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import MySQLdb.cursors
import re

app = Flask(__name__)
 
app.secret_key = 'your secret key'
 
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = '127.0.0.1'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = ''
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'ibm_db'
 
mysql = MySQL(app)

@app.route('/')
# @app.route('/login')
# def login():
#     return render_template('login.html')
# @app.route('/index')
# def index():
#     return render_template('index.html')

# @app.route('/logout')
# def logout():
#     session.pop('loggedin', None)
#     session.pop('email', None)
#     return redirect(url_for('login')) 

@app.route('/index', methods =['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    msg = ''
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'email' in request.form and 'password' in request.form:
        email = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['password']
        username = request.form['username']
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
        # MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = % s', (email, ))
        account = cursor.fetchone()
        if account:
            msg = 'Account already exists !'
            return render_template('index.html',msg=msg)
        elif not re.match(r'[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+', email):
            msg = 'Invalid email address !'
        elif not email or not password:
            msg = 'Please fill out the form !'
            return render_template('index.html',msg=msg)
        else:
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO accounts(username,email,password) VALUES (username,email,password)')
            mysql.connection.commit()
            cursor.close()
            msg = 'You have successfully registered !'
            return "<h1>Welcome</h1>"
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        msg = 'Please fill out the form !'
        return render_template('index.html',msg=msg)
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')
@app.route('/login', methods =['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    msg = ''
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'email' in request.form and 'password' in request.form:
        email = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['password']
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = % s AND password = % s', (email, password, ))
        account = cursor.fetchone()
        if account:
            # session['loggedin'] = True
            # session['id'] = account['id']
            # session['email'] = account['email']
            msg = 'Logged in successfully !'
            return "<h1>Welcome</h1>"
        else:
            msg = 'Incorrect email / password !'
            return render_template('login.html', msg = msg)
    else:
        return render_template('login.html')
```

I want a solution for this problem. Help me to solve this problem

Comment: `cursor.execute('INSERT INTO accounts(username,email,password) VALUES (username,email,password)')` you are not handling the variables for username, email, password correctly here. You need to resolve the variables into a proper sql statement - as it is, the three variables are not resolved and the sql is not valid either.

Answer (score 0):

Check your insert statement, a proper way to do it could by

```
cursor.execute(
    """ 
        INSERT INTO accounts(username,email,password)
        VALUES (%s, %s, %s) 
    """, 
    (username,email,password)
)

mysql.connection.commit()
```